# Replace 24VAC 20VA transformer with standard power supply

Tags: power-supply, transformer

I have the following transformer ([source](https://www.microframecorp.com/9100-0101-led-display-power-adapter-with-20-ft-wire)):

[image: 24VAC 20VA transformer]

Sticker reads:

```
Pri: 120VAC 60Hz 30W
Sec:  24VAC 20VA
```

I want to replace it with a standard, power supply without screw terminals. Preferably, I want one that will plug into the female end of this cable ([source](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/tensility-international-corp/CA-2216/CP-2216-ND/1129479)):

[image: digikey power cable]

How do I translate these numbers to make sure I buy a compatible power supply that doesn't require screwing the wires into the plug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary winding rating tells you (effectively) the compatibility for mains power in your region, so make sure a replacement is also rated for 120VAC and 60Hz.

The secondary winding rating tells you most of what you need to know to size the power supply. In this case it's a 5:1 step-down transformer (changing 120 to 24 volts), then 20VA means it supplies up to 20 watts of "apparent" power. *(The discussion of real versus apparent power (VA versus watts) can get rather technical, because it depends on the type of device you are powering.)*

You should find a replacement that provides at *least* the same minimum power (20VA). If you treat this as 20 watts, you can calculate (\$P=IE\$) that the secondary side is providing about 0.83 amperes. It doesn't hurt to have extra current capacity, so if you find a 24VAC 1A or 24VAC 2A supply, it will work.

Finding a power supply with the correct socket to match the cable you have might be more challenging. The connectors are usually referred to as a "2.1mm DC barrel jack" style (even though your transformer outputs AC). Hopefully that will provide you with some specs and keywords to find what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The power supply you buy must also provide 24VAC as its output...neither higher nor lower, and not 24VDC. You need the power rating to be **at least** 20VA. If the replacement doesn't have a VA rating but specifies an output current then I would look for at least 1A output current.